# Как получить значение из списка выбора RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Разбираюсь со списками выбора RoR и не могу понять как получить выбранное значение для дальнейшей работы.

Есть категории (title и body). Делаю список выбора, для выбора нужной категории. Изначально показываются все категории, хочу сделать, чтобы из выпадающего списка можно было выбрать нужную категорию, и почле этого только она отображалась!

Делаю

`<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(Category.all.map { |category| [category.title, category.id] }, :selected => :category_id)) %>`

Появляется выпадающий список, с категориями. Как передать выбранное значения, для того ,чтобы передать его для отображения:

`<% @categories.each do |category| %>
        <h2><%= category.title %></h2>
<%end%>`

Comment: Ничего не понятно :( В селекте вы выбираете определённую категорию и при этом у всех категорий должен поменяться title? Попробуйте добавить больше кода и подробнее описать проблему и ожидаемый результат. Ну и при выборе чего-либо в селекте в вашей базе данных ничего не изменится. Нужно отправить форму и обработать данные в экшне контроллера. А если речь не об изменениях в БД, то нужно будет добавить немного джаваскрипта

Comment: В БД ничего менять не надо. В БД будут категории. По умолчанию на странице отображаются все категории. А пользователь просто с выпадающего списка может выбрать нужную категорию (и при этом выборе, просто вместо всех категорий, должна отобразиться только та, что была выбрана в списке выбора). По сути работа только с view.

Comment: Прошу прощения, сейчас нет времени на полноценный ответ, попробую на днях добраться. Вам нужно во вьюхе добавить айдишник категории к названию класса (например) того блока, который отвечает за отображение категории. И написать немного js - при изменении селекта показывать только один блок, остальные прятать

Comment: Спасибо. Я что то подобное и думал. По айди категории отображать. Но не могу понять как получить значение выбранного айди в селекте.

Comment: `$('select').val()` не работает? Попробуйте `$('select option:selected').val()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750307/jquery-select-change-event-get-selected-option - богатый выбор вариантов

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы. Буду пробовать!

Comment: Будет здорово, если вы добавите ответ к своему вопросу после того, как решите его :)